# Is there a software that can open multiple terminals and ssh to different server?

Tags: ssh

I am looking for a software such that I can manage multiple terminals at the same time on mac.

What I want is that I can open and ssh to multiple server by opening one terminal for each ssh session.

Just wonder is there any outstanding software that I can do it?

Comment: I believe Putty would be the way to go for that.

Comment: Terminal.app has been tabbed for awhile now, like a browser. You can have it open multiple tabs on startup, and it can be configured to open ssh to a specific address automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTerm2 is a freely-available replacement for OS X's built-in Terminal app. It supports multiple windows and tabs, just like the built-in app - but also offers extended window management, with the ability to split windows into horizontal and vertical panes, and save/restore terminal window positions/configurations.

Combine it with the command-line SSH tool that ships with OS X and it will do pretty much everything you want.

You can grab iTerm 2 from here: http://iterm2.com

You may also find tmux interesting: http://tmux.sourceforge.net

(the easiest way to install tmux on OS X is via the Homebrew package manager for OS X)

Comment: I second tmux. It may take you a bit longer to learn, but makes everything so much faster and easier once you learn it.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using GNU screen. It is not quite as nice as tmux, but the advantage is that it is pre-installed on most linux servers that you log into. In this way you can actually have multiple tabs on one server without having to re-log in for each tab. You can actually configure it to have one screen session on your local machine and another on the server which gets confusing but is very powerful once you get used to it.

http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/